# did the plumber install the pipes correctly in my bathroom?

Tags: plumbing

I have a question: did the plumber install the pipes correctly in my bathroom? Are the pipes too close to each other, especially the crossing ones? Should the plumber rearrange it?

[image]

Comment: Not an expert but I don't see a problem as long as the PEX clears the back face of whatever kind of wallboard will be used.  I would consider some nailing plates on the studs where the pipe is though.  I'm curious as to the reason for transition to copper...looks like new copper.

Comment: That looks like a very well done plumbing job.

Comment: @Huesmann copper stub-outs at fixture connection points remain common in PEX installs.

Comment: There aren't many other options for running the PEX supply lines to get them to where they're needed other than "looping" them around the drain line. Looks good to me.

Comment: thank you all very much for answering

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be in need of some protective plates (pipes less than 1-1/2" from the edge of framing and need protection from being nailed/screwed into) and possibly some steel reinforcements (stud shoes) for the studs (which will also serve as nailing plates for the side they are installed from) that are drilled almost to nothing. Even for a non-bearing wall, the hole should not be more than 60% of the stud width, (so 2.1 inches for a 2x4 that's actually 3.5" wide these days) and unless the camera is playing tricks, I have my doubts. Stud shoes are a way around that limit.

Both of those may well be on the "do another day" list rather than "the plumber is incompetent" so just make sure they get done before drywall goes on.

The crossing pipes are not a big concern, though I personally would like a protective plate extending over them in case of someone missing the stud and drilling/nailing/screwing into them, but code does not *require* that outside of framing.

Comment: i do the alpha clips when pushing though framing to prevent the pex squeak.  don't really like the propress with a oring about as good as a sharkbite but plumbers love it for barrier to entry.

Comment: Yup, it's quick, it involves no fire, and it makes it a pain in the butt to repair or change anything, since the fittings are purely "use-once, cut out, throw away" and the tooling is very expensive. So of course plumbers love it.